# Passing Node.js middleware to a custom function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

Question about express middleware.  Say I have a route like the following:

```
router.route('/replies/:board')
    .post(bodyThreadIdVal, textVal, passVal, replyHandler.postReply)
```

Now let's say I wanted to move the first three middleware arguments from above out of the `post` method and into a custom method I created in another file, named `postReply`.  How would I go about doing this?  I thought maybe using `app.use` within my `postReply` method but not sure exactly how or if there is a cleaner way.

I have tried a few methods including

```
this.postReply = async (req, res, next) => {
    app.use(bodyThreadIdVal, textVal, passVal)(req, res, next)
    /* additional code */
}
```

But this seems to cause a recursive loop that rejects with `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason of moving middlewares into a sepparate file is groupping them in one place and making code cleaner and there is no necessity to create a function that will combine your middlewares then I would suggest to group such connected middlewares into an array:

```
const postReply = [bodyThreadIdVal, textVal, passVal];

router.route('/replies/:board')
    .post(...postReply, replyHandler.postReply);
```

If you will need to add some `/* additional code */` just create a new middleware and add it to `postReply` array. This is definitely much cleaner way.